# Selenium Cucumber: Feature file is unable to find step definitions through runner class

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, maven, cucumber

I am facing an issue while automating a web site, when I am executing the code by my Runner Class the feature file is not able to find or read the Step Definition class. Below are the details.

### Runner Class:

```
package StepDefinition;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;        
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber; 

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)  
@CucumberOptions(   
        features = {"src/test/resources/Features"}, 
        monochrome = true,
        plugin = {"pretty","junit:target/JUnitReports/report.xml",
                "json:target/JSONReports/report.json", 
                "html:target/HTMLReports"},
        glue={"StepDefinition"},
        strict = true,
       tags= {"@Login, @Home"}
       // ,dryRun = true
        )

public class RunnerClass {  
}
```

### Feature File:

@Login
Feature: login check

Scenario: Check if user can login
Given User is on login page
When User enters  and 
And I click on the login button
Then I Print succesfully logged in

### Step Definition Class:

```
package StepDefinition;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import PageFactory.LoginPage_PF;
import Utils.DriverFactory;
import cucumber.api.PendingException;
import io.cucumber.java.en.And;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;

public class LoginDemoSteps_PF extends DriverFactory {

    //WebDriver driver=null;
    LoginPage_PF login;

    
    @Given("^User is on login page$")
    public void browser_open() throws Throwable{

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\automation\\chrome driver new version\\87\\chromedriver.exe");
         driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.navigate().to("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/");
        throw new PendingException();
    
    }
    
    @When("^User enters (.*) and (.*)$")
    public void loginpage(String username,String password) throws InterruptedException {
         
        login=new LoginPage_PF(driver);
        login.EnterCredentials(username, password);
    }
    
    @And("^I click on the login button$")
    public void hit_enter(){

        login.btnClick();
}
    
    @Then("^I Print succesfully logged in$")
    public void successful_login(){

        System.out.println("Login Successfully Done");
}
    
}
```

### Errors:

@Login
Feature: login check

Scenario: Check if user can login            # Alogin.feature:4
Given User is on login page
When User enters  and 
And I click on the login button
Then I Print succesfully logged in
@Home
Feature: Home Page

Scenario: Go to admin page     # Bhome.feature:4
And I wait again for a while
Then I click on Admin button

Undefined scenarios:
Alogin.feature:4 # Scenario: Check if user can login
Bhome.feature:4 # Scenario: Go to admin page

2 Scenarios (2 undefined)
6 Steps (6 undefined)
0m0.000s

You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

```
@Given("^User is on login page$")
public void user_is_on_login_page() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@When("^User enters <username> and <password>$")
public void user_enters_username_and_password() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@When("^I click on the login button$")
public void i_click_on_the_login_button() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@Then("^I Print succesfully logged in$")
public void i_Print_succesfully_logged_in() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@Given("^I wait again for a while$")
public void i_wait_again_for_a_while() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@Then("^I click on Admin button$")
public void i_click_on_Admin_button() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

### Exceptions:

```
cucumber.api.PendingException: TODO: implement me
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.JUnitReporter.addFailure(JUnitReporter.java:134)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.JUnitReporter.addFailureOrIgnoreStep(JUnitReporter.java:122)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.JUnitReporter.result(JUnitReporter.java:91)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:280)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:48)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:91)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
```

Comment: The stack trace is a bit weird but is actually caused by the pending exception in your step definition.

Comment: yes, but i am still unable to trace the issue..Any idea?

Comment: Remove all the `throw new PendingException();` from your code and see what happens.

Comment: It's right after `driver.navigate()`